# Xcode Windows Problem !

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am facing a strange problem . When i single click on my files in the left pane of Xcode window. The file doesnt automatically show on the right pane. I have to double click on my classes files or resources files to open them . It was working fine since yesterday. Does anyone has any idea wats wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly! I think you were working with multiple files and opened these files in right pane. when you click on image in left pane the image will show in the current(focused window) in right pane and then if you click on any file the image window would not get refreshed. The file you have clicked opened in the another window (minimized window). To resolve your problem - click on the close button in upper right corner (second button look like a rectangle), this will close the current window. Close all the windows now click on the file in left pane, it will show up in the right pane window.